Why is this query using filesort?
I am looking at my slow query logs and trying to fix some of slow queries, I identified one to fix and ran EXPLAIN on it and noticed it using filesort
Why would the following query show "using filesort"
Here is the EXPLAIN

Here are all the indexs

Here is the index I want to use:


MySQL uses "filesort" when it can't assume that it reads the rows in the order you requested.
MySQL (specifically, InnoDB) always reads rows in some index order -- the index named for the first joined table in the EXPLAIN.
If I test your query but change it to ...ORDER BY power we see that it eliminates the filesort, and the key column shows that it's using the index on (titan, power).
CREATE TABLE titan_json (
  id SERIAL,
  titan VARCHAR(20),
  power INT,
  json JSON,
  userID INT,
  guildID INT,
  guild VARCHAR(20),
  INDEX (titan, power)
);

EXPLAIN
SELECT json FROM titan_json WHERE titan='Cronos' ORDER BY power;

+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | titan_json | NULL       | ref  | titan         | titan | 83      | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+

But if I sort by an expression as in your query — or really any expression — MySQL doesn't assume the order it fetches rows is the same as the order the query requested. So it must filesort.
EXPLAIN
SELECT json FROM titan_json WHERE titan='Cronos' ORDER BY ABS(power-500000);

+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | titan_json | NULL       | ref  | titan         | titan | 83      | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+----------+----------------+

If I create a new index with a functional part for the expression in your ORDER BY clause, and re-test the query, we see that it can rely on the index order and eliminate the filesort.
ALTER TABLE titan_json
  ADD KEY (titan, (ABS(power-500000)));

EXPLAIN
SELECT json FROM titan_json WHERE titan='Cronos' ORDER BY ABS(power-500000);

+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+------------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys          | key              | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+------------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | titan_json | NULL       | ref  | titan,functional_index | functional_index | 83      | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+------------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+

Note you must be using MySQL 8.0 or later for the feature of functional key parts. I executed these tests on MySQL 8.0.37.

Thanks for the detailed answer, this is really helpful. I assume the function_index only works if the -500000 is a static value. If the value was dynamic we couldn't have an index

Yes, the value is hard-coded, so the optimizer uses the index only if the expression matches the index definition exactly. If the value is different from day to day, you'll have to make do with the filesort in this case.

Does the filesort only happen on the resulting rows after the WHERE conditions e.g.  If I did WHERE titan='Cronos'  AND power >= 490000 AND <= 510000 ORDER by ABS(power-500000), would i be "file sorting" less rows?

Yes, a filesort is done on the query result. That occurs after rows have been eliminated by conditions (both indexed conditions and non-indexed conditions), expressions in the select-list have been evaluated, and any aggregation has reduced groups of rows.
